# Need help Configuring a test event for an aws Lambda function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, testing, aws-lambda

I want to update this Lambda function to python3.9 from 3.6. I want to create a test event to make sure everything still works after I do this. I'm new to Lambda and this function was created before my time. Any help or a point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Below is the function code:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please do not post code as screenshots, but use properly formatted code blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend that you look at recent CloudWatch Logs for this Lambda function. The code is logging the received event (which can be one of 2 types: Create and Update). Try to find a log for each event type. Then fabricate some test events from those logs.

And don't rely on Lambda function test events because they are not persistent (as you have seen). Create your own 'real' tests and revision-control them like code.